# Running VS Code in Windows Server 2012R2 pegs CPU

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-server-2012

Has anyone be able to run VS Code on Windows Server 2012R2? I have tried running the application normally and in compatibility mode(s). And each time running the app pegs the CPU to 100% utilization.

Does anyone have any suggestions or know if the app cannot be run on Windows Server OS?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/17097) with VSCode running on vm machines using a single cpu. Some users have experienced that adding an addition cpu solve the issue.